# Threshold in McCullock-Pitts Neuron model (MCP)

Tags: python, machine-learning

According to the MCP model, we use the Heaviside step function:

[image: Heaviside step function]

where z is the net input, given that m is the total number of samples, i is a particular feature of the sample and w and x refers to the weight and sample vectors respectively. **However**, we can shift theta to the left hand side, and let w0 = -theta and x0 = 1. Thus the condition for the output = 1 should be when z greater or equals to 0.

[image: net input calculation]

We use this as the activation function for our **Perceptron** algorithm (our neuron network). Here are the two rules that govern the machine learning:

1. Initialize the weights to 0 or a small random variables
2. For each training sample x^{j} perform the following

   - Compute the output value, y (predicted class label)
   - Update the weights

The weights are updated by adding delta w to the individual weights:
[delta w calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLw1U.png)
where eta is the learning rate and y and y hat are the true class label and predicted class labels respectively.

Here is the Perceptron algorithm in question (python3)

```py
import numpy

class Perceptron:
  def __init__(self, eta=0.01, n_iter=10):
    self.eta = eta
    self.n_iter=10 ## total number iterations to run the algorithm on the given samples
  def fit(self, X, y): ## X represents a matrix entity
    self.w_ = np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1]) ## w_ are the weights. +1 because first element is theta
    for _ in range(self.n_iter):
      for xi, target in zip(X, y):
        update = self.eta * (target-self.predict(xi))
        self.w_[1:] += update*xi ## update weights
        self.w_[0] += update ## update theta (?)
  return self

  def net_input(self,X):
    return np.dot(X,self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]
  def predict(self,X):
    return np.where(self.net_input(X)>=0.0, 1, -1) ## Heaviside step function
```

**tl;dr starts here**

1. With reference to MCP model, what is the threshold (theta) there for? It seems that the algorithm works just fine even when I treat theta as zero (or even remove it completely). Is it then because of the sample of data I used? (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data)
2. Are the weights themselves not sufficient in adjusting the values of the net input for a sample with respect to 0 (assuming theta is no longer there)?
3. How can we treat theta as a weight? it seems that in the algorithm theta is changing according to the samples as it the  *fits*  function iterates through them in the inner for loop.

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT**
Each line represents the weights at a particular instance of the inner for loop.
Here are the values of the weights when the threshold (self.w_[0]) is left in the code:

```py
[0.   0.38 0.66]
[0.   0.76 1.32]
[-0.2   0.22  1.68]
[-0.2   0.34  2.1 ]
[-0.4  -0.68  1.82]
[-0.4  -0.68  1.82]
[-0.4  -0.68  1.82]
[-0.4  -0.68  1.82]
[-0.4  -0.68  1.82]
[-0.4  -0.68  1.82]
```

And here what happens to the weights when the threshold is removed:

```py
[0.38 0.66]
[0.76 1.32]
[0.16 1.7 ]
[0.16 2.02]
[-0.86  1.74]
[-0.86  1.74]
[-0.86  1.74]
[-0.86  1.74]
[-0.86  1.74]
[-0.86  1.74]
```